# How to distinguish different tags with the same name in XML by using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, element, elementtree

I would like to extract specific elements from one xml file. But there are many same tags in the xml. If we have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns="SimpleClass">
  <Class name="AcademicInstitution" is_persistent="false">
    <attrs name="name" is_primary="true" type="/11"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Company" is_persistent="false" parent="/9">
    <attrs name="manager" is_primary="false" type="/3"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Faculty" is_persistent="false" parent="/0">
    <attrs name="address" is_primary="false" type="/7"/>
    <attrs name="dean" is_primary="false" type="/3"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Person" is_persistent="true">
    <attrs name="name" is_primary="true" type="/11"/>
    <attrs name="works_for" is_primary="false" type="/9"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Document" is_persistent="true">
    <attrs name="number" is_primary="true" type="/10"/>
    <attrs name="author" is_primary="false" type="/3"/>
    <attrs name="content" is_primary="false" type="/11"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Student" is_persistent="false" parent="/3">
    <attrs name="studiesIn" is_primary="false" type="/6"/>
    <attrs name="supervisor" is_primary="false" type="/3"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="University" is_persistent="false" parent="/9">
    <attrs name="faculty" is_primary="false" type="/2"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Address" is_persistent="false">
    <attrs name="city" is_primary="false" type="/11"/>
    <attrs name="street" is_primary="false" type="/11"/>
    <attrs name="postcode" is_primary="false" type="/11"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Task" is_persistent="true">
    <attrs name="name" is_primary="true" type="/11"/>
    <attrs name="number" is_primary="true" type="/10"/>
    <attrs name="description" is_primary="false" type="/4"/>
  </Class>
  <Class name="Organization" is_persistent="true">
    <attrs name="name" is_primary="true" type="/11"/>
    <attrs name="address" is_primary="false" type="/7"/>
  </Class>
  <PrimitiveDataType name="Integer"/>
  <PrimitiveDataType name="String"/>
  <Association name="address" src="/3" dest="/7"/>
  <Association name="performsTask" src="/3" dest="/8"/>
</xmi:XMI>
```

We can find that there are many 'Class' tags and 'attrs' tags.

I can get tags by the following code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test2.xmi')
root = tree.getroot()

for ele in tree.getiterator():
    _, _, tag = ele.tag.rpartition('}')
```

The ouput is:

```
XMI
Class
attrs
Class
attrs
Class
attrs
attrs
...
```

The output I want is:

```
Class(Class0)
attrs(Class0)
Class(Class1)
attrs(Class1)
Class(Class2)
attrs(Class2)
attrs(Class2)
...
```

My thought is using Python ElementTree to parse xml file and get tag. But I don't know how to assign a unique label (such as: 'Tag'+number) to each tag. Also, how to let each sub-node to get the unique label of their father-node(`Class(Class0) and attrs(Class0)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have done:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test2.xmi')
root = tree.getroot()

for i in range(0,len(root)):
    _, _, roottag = root[i].tag.rpartition('}')
    for ele in root[i].getiterator():
        _, _, tag = ele.tag.rpartition('}')
        print str(tag)+"("+str(roottag)+str(i)+")"
```

If anyone has better idea, I‘m glad to hear it!